# AJAX POST image dataURL to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, html5-canvas

I'm currently having a problem sending an AJAX POST over to a PHP file, on success I'm receiving blank data when I use console.log(data). I'm using html canvas to let a user draw on the picture and then convert the canvas to a dataURL. Once converted, I'm trying to send the dataURL to my PHP file so I can convert it and display it within an email message or as an email attachment. I tried different URL links, I'm currently using my localhost.

This is my code for ajax post:

```
function saveCanvas() {

       var canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');
       var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:80/form.php',
        data: { 'image' : dataURL},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

When I console.log it out, I get a blank response. I'm just trying to post the data to my form.php file, I tried almost every different way of the url, but no success with anything. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without your php code. For now, check the browser's network tab and see respond and request are same as you excepted.

Comment: Please show the php file